# Python - print items with empty space separator

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

given this html:

```
<div id="catwrap" class="categories">
    <a href="http://blahblahblahscience.com/category/electronic/" style="background-color:#006666">Electronic</a>
    <a href="http://blahblahblahscience.com/category/track-reviews/" style="background-color:">Track Reviews</a>                
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I use this `Beautifulsoup` code to extract `Electronic` and `Track Reviews`:

```
tags = post.find('div', id='catwrap')
for t in tags:
    print t.get_text()
```

it works, but data comes like this:

`ElectronicTrack Reviews`

how do I insert space in a `for loop`, so it outputs:

`Electronic Track Reviews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't actually found each tag individually - you've only found the `div` containing the tag links, and are printing the text inside that container (which will be all the text of the links but without spaces in between).

To get the tags themselves, you need to do something like this instead:

```
tags = post.find('div', id='catwrap')[0].find('a')
```

Then your for loop will run once per tag, printing each one on a new line. At the moment it's not that the loop isn't printing a space between iterations, the problem is that there is *only one iteration* and the output of get_text doesn't have spaces where you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `for` loop, use `join`:

```
print(" ".join([t.get_text() for t in tags]))
```

Comment: He doesn't need a list either, if he's using a version of Python that has generator expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieving that by concatenating a space.

```
tags = post.find('div', id='catwrap')
for t in tags:
    print t.get_text() + " "      # this will concatenate a space at the end of each item
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmmmm, 
I usually do the whole thing at the first place. So if it's me it'll be like this:

```
a = []
tags = post.find('div', id='catwrap')
for t in tags:
   a.push(t.get_text())
print a.join(" ")
```

Do you think that'll what you need?